# Empty constructor doesn't get executed

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a class with 2 constructors. An empty one where I initialize each member to a default value, and a constructor with parameters where I initialize each member to those parameters:

Sesion.h

```
class Sesion
{
  public:
    Sesion();
    Sesion(int idUser, int codUser, int idVehicle, int codVehicle);

    Sesion& operator= (const Sesion& sesion);


    //Getters
    int getIdSesion() const;

    int getIdUser() const;

    int getCodUser() const;

    int getIdVehicle() const;

    int getCodVehicle() const;

    //Setters
    void setIdSesion(int idSesion);
    
  private:
    int idSesion;
    int idUser;
    int codUser;
    int idVehicle;
    int codVehicle;   
};
```

Sesion.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Sesion::Sesion()
{
  cout << "Empty constructor called" << endl;
  idSesion = -1;
  idUser= -1;
  codUser = -1;
  idVehicle = -1;
  codVehicle = -1;
}

Sesion::Sesion(int idUser, int codUser, int idVehicle, int codVehicle)
{
  this->idSesion = -1;
  this->idUser = idUser;
  this->codUser = codUser;
  this->idVehicle = idVehicle;
  this->codVehicle = codVehicle;
}

int Sesion::getIdSesion() const
{
  return idSesion;
}
...
```

So when I try to execute this in another part of the program:

```
Sesion sesion;
sesion.getIdSesion();
```

The value of `IdSesion` is **1994327248** when it should be **-1**. If I execute the program several times I get different values, but the 1994 at the beginning stays the same.

I know the empty constructor isn't executing because the cout never prints anything so, what constructor is getting called when I create the object?

I am compiling this program for two different platforms. On the first one I use Qt 4.8.6 and on the other one I use Qt 5.2.1.

On the first platform the program doesn't behave correctly, as I just explained. On the second platform the empty constructor gets called correctly and the value of `IdSesion` is **-1**.

I don't have right now the information about what C++ standards I'm using to compile for each platform, but I know I'm using a different one for each of them.

The only thing I can say is that on the first platform I can't use foreach loops while in the other platform I can, so maybe you know which standards I'm probably using.

Also the main problem is that I am only able to use a debugger on the second platform, where it works correctly. On the first platform I don't have a debugger available so I'm "blind" and I can only include print statements to follow the code when I execute it.

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/94o74a11T. Please post a [mcve]. The definition of `int getIdSesion() const;` is missing and with the canonical implementation `sesion.getIdSesion();` is not doing anything.

Comment: Can you add body of getIdSesion() method, just in case :)

Comment: Sure, the code is now edited.

Comment: it's Session, not Sesion :)

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen Yes, I noticed when I had already posted the question. If  you see that the naming is off it's because the code is originaly written in my language and I half-translated it when I wrote the question.

Comment: This is still not a [mcve].

Comment: A debugger is an essential tool. Would you weld without a welding hood? Install gdb from sources if it's not already installed, or figure out why you cannot use it and fix that. If you cannot use a debugger, just don't develop on that platform.

Comment: Yes, my plan is to include a debugger next time we update the platform. But it is not that easy. The platform is a specialized machine with a custom Linux. And it doesn't have a lot of the basic programming utilities like make or gdb because it is not meant to be a programming environment. The programming environment is an actual computer with Ubuntu (what I called second platform). I didn't decide any of this and I would change it if I could. Right now my IDE is somehow compiling things for the machine so I have to learn how it's doing it and then maybe I can compile gdb or whatever I need.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor does run as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/TlYAhIUEh)

There are some improvements that i would suggest in addition:

1. Always use **header guards** in header files as shown [here](https://onlinegdb.com/TlYAhIUEh). Header guards are used to prevent duplicate definitions in a given single file. For example, lets say we have:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 4;  //this is okay
    int a = 3;  //this won't compile i.e., gives compilation error
    return 0;
}
```

as shown in the above code example, we cannot define the same object twice(or duplicate definition). The important thing to remember is that there should not be duplicate definitions.

Now lets say we have a header named `file.h` which have the following content:

**file.h**

```
int func()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Then we have another file named **file2.h** as:

**file2.h**

```
#include "file.h"
```

Finally say we have our **main.cpp** as:

```
#include "file.h" //this means copy the content of file.h
#include "file2.h" //this means copy the content of file2.h

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The above program won't compile!. This is because **main.cpp** has included the function definition of `func` twice. First when we have written `#include "file.h"` the content of file.h gets copied into main.cpp. Similarly when we write `#include "file2.h"` the content of file2.h gets copied into main.cpp. But wait file2.h itself has a `#include "file.h"` which means file2.h has the definition of `func`. And this definition of `func` again gets copied into main.cpp. So essentially, **main.cpp** has duplicate definitions of function `func`. As i said we can't have duplicate definitions, so this program won't compile.

To prevent this compilation error we use header guards. So if add header guards to `file.h` you will note that the program compile successfully now. Similarly you should also add header guard to `geometry.h` so that it cannot be included more than once inside a translation unit.

2. Instead of assigning values to data members inside the constructor, you can/should use **constructor initializer list**. So the constructor would [look](https://onlinegdb.com/laLT_R0ak) like :

```
Sesion::Sesion(): idSesion(-1), idUser(-1), codUser(-1), idVehicle(-1),codVehicle(-1)
{
  std::cout << "Empty constructor called" << std::endl;
  
}
```

3. Always initialize any built-in type inside block scope. This is because if don't then they have *garbage value*. That is, use in-class initializers for built-in type. So this would like:

```
class Session
{
 //some other code here 

 private:
    int idSesion = -1;    //initialize built in type
    int idUser = -1;       //initialize built in type
    int codUser = -1;     //initialize built in type
    int idVehicle = -1;   //initialize built in type 
    int codVehicle = -1;  //initialize built in type
};
```

The advantage of this is that if you(for some reason) forget to initialize these data members using constructor initiaizer list or assigning to them inside the body of the constructor then these members will have these values by default.

Comment: Okay, so I actually use header guards because the IDE generates them automatically, but I didn't include them in the code. But could you explain what are they used for?

Comment: @CarlosPeñas Header guards are used to prevent duplicate definitions in a given single file. Check out my edit of point 1. There i have explained why header guards are needed.

Comment: I've tried options 2 and 3 separately and together, but I'm still getting the same idSesion value (1994314960). If it works like this with option 3  then it makes me think that this value that I'm seeing is not the classic random un-initialized value. It seems that first IdSesion is initialized  to -1 and then instead of calling my empty constructor, another implicit constructor that changes the value is being called.

Comment: @CarlosPeñas Try copying all of your files into a different directory. And then compiling your program in that directory. You can copy paste the complete program into the new files you create inside the new directory from the following link: https://onlinegdb.com/QYG9m0iro . Also, this time use point 3 of my answer. Also use `std::cout<<sesion.getIdSesion();` to print out the value and confirm that it prints -1. Update me if this solves your problem.

Comment: Okay, so if I compile a program in a different directory with only the main() and the Sesion class I get the expected value of -1, even on the first platform. But if I compile the whole application together (with all the Qt windows and everything) it still gives me the other value. As a note, this problem has started to happen today. The same code worked correctly in the past, so I don't know what to think anymore.

Comment: @CarlosPeñas Try **Cleaning** your complete build directory. And building your whole project(including Qt windows etc etc) again. As the correct value -1 is printed when you compile the files separately, i think we can safely say that the unexpected value 1994327248 is not because of any undefined behavior in these(main.cpp, sesion.cpp, sesion.h) files. Update me if cleaning the build directory and building the project again helps.  PS: You can even try to create a new directory and build your whole project in this new directory and see if this works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to re-create the project on another directoy. I'll let you know if I come to any conclusion